# How to convert dataframe into matrix using R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I need to transform a dataframe like this:

```
> test
   day_1 Freq_1    Percent_1 day_2      Freq_2    Percent_2 day_3       Freq_3    Percent_3
1    104   1514  1.720063622   847 23.11370681 4.368660e-02    14  0.004547728 2.068183e-05
2     37  11754 13.353783231   994 16.67422696 3.151551e-02   760  0.009095457 4.136367e-05
3    277  11689 13.279936378  <NA>          NA           NA   371  0.013643185 6.204550e-05
4   1622  20314 23.078845717   153  5.08996749 9.620412e-03   737  0.018190914 8.272733e-05
5    277  11689 13.279936378   994 16.67422696 3.151551e-02    92  0.022738642 1.034092e-04
6   1622  20314 23.078845717   847 23.11370681 4.368660e-02   534  0.027286370 1.240910e-04
7   1677     96  0.109066121   964  0.17766689 3.358035e-04   302  0.031834099 1.447728e-04
8     37  11754 13.353783231   994 16.67422696 3.151551e-02   185  0.036381827 1.654547e-04
9   1073   1405  1.596228130  <NA>          NA           NA    51  0.040929556 1.861365e-04
10  1622  20314 23.078845717   847 23.11370681 4.368660e-02     4  0.045477284 2.068183e-04
11   702  20110 22.847080209  <NA>          NA           NA   289  0.050025013 2.275002e-04
```

in

```
    |  847   |   14    |  994 
104 | 23.1137|   0     |   0
847 |   0    | 0.00454 |   0
37  |   0    |   0     |  16.674
```

The rownames and colnames are the days (day_1,day_2,day_3) and the string are the Freq of the second day analyzed. The row is the first day analyzed and the second day is the column.
When the NAs are present to make the linked with the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="day_1 Freq_1    Percent_1 day_2      Freq_2    Percent_2 day_3       Freq_3    Percent_3
104   1514  1.720063622   847 23.11370681 4.368660e-02    14  0.004547728 2.068183e-05
37  11754 13.353783231   994 16.67422696 3.151551e-02   760  0.009095457 4.136367e-05
277  11689 13.279936378  <NA>          NA           NA   371  0.013643185 6.204550e-05
1622  20314 23.078845717   153  5.08996749 9.620412e-03   737  0.018190914 8.272733e-05
277  11689 13.279936378   994 16.67422696 3.151551e-02    92  0.022738642 1.034092e-04
1622  20314 23.078845717   847 23.11370681 4.368660e-02   534  0.027286370 1.240910e-04
1677     96  0.109066121   964  0.17766689 3.358035e-04   302  0.031834099 1.447728e-04
37  11754 13.353783231   994 16.67422696 3.151551e-02   185  0.036381827 1.654547e-04
1073   1405  1.596228130  <NA>          NA           NA    51  0.040929556 1.861365e-04
1622  20314 23.078845717   847 23.11370681 4.368660e-02     4  0.045477284 2.068183e-04
702  20110 22.847080209  <NA>          NA           NA   289  0.050025013 2.275002e-04", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Try the following

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(-starts_with("Percent")) %>%
  group_by(G = row_number()) %>%
  nest %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~.x %>% gather(key, value))) %>%
  unnest %>%
  separate(key, "_", into=c("word", "num")) %>%
  group_by(G, num) %>%
  spread(word, value) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(day = as.numeric(day), Freq = as.numeric(Freq)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(day)) %>%
  group_by(G) %>%
  mutate(prev_day = dplyr::lag(day, 1)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(prev_day)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-G, -num) %>%
  group_by(prev_day, row_number()) %>%
  spread(day, Freq, fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 19 x 17
   # prev_day `row_number()`    `4`    `14`   `51`   `92` `153`  `185`  `289`  `302`  `371`  `534`  `737`   `760` `847` `964` `994`
      # <dbl>          <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 # 1       37              3 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0      16.7
 # 2       37             14 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0      16.7
 # 3      104              1 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0        23.1 0       0  
 # 4      153              7 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0.0182 0         0   0       0  
 # 5      277              5 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0.0136 0      0      0         0   0       0  
 # 6      277              8 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0      16.7
 # 7      702             19 0      0       0      0       0    0      0.0500 0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
 # 8      847              2 0      0.00455 0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
 # 9      847             11 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0.0273 0      0         0   0       0  
# 10      847             18 0.0455 0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
# 11      964             13 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0.0318 0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
# 12      994              4 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0.00910   0   0       0  
# 13      994              9 0      0       0      0.0227  0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
# 14      994             15 0      0       0      0       0    0.0364 0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
# 15     1073             16 0      0       0.0409 0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
# 16     1622              6 0      0       0      0       5.09 0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0       0  
# 17     1622             10 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0        23.1 0       0  
# 18     1622             17 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0        23.1 0       0  
# 19     1677             12 0      0       0      0       0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0         0   0.178   0
```